# Anchor tag not going to the expected area

Tags: html, css

I am making a personal website and am putting all of my content on one page.

[image]

When I click "Home", it would go to the first section, "Resume" to that section, etc. I put the border around "Resume" to test if when the anchor is clicked, it would pull up to that section (and it does work!), but it's a bit off:

[image]

This is when I click "Resume". A chunk of it is cut off because you can't see the top border. I'm wondering why the anchor doesn't pull me to the top of "Resume", but instead goes a little bit more inwards? Here's the relevant code:

```
        <a name="resume-page" id="resume-page"></a>

        <div class="resumepage">
            <div class="jumbotron" id="header3">
                <h1>Resume</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor likely *is* putting the top of your screen at the correct anchor position, it's just that your navigation bar is overlapping that space.

To make it so it would behave like you expect, you can relatively position your anchors, making their `top` value the negative of the height of your navigation bar to counteract the content that it's overlapping.

Comment: So I set the `top` value to be -25px, but that means that the nav bar is only showing half of it. How do I go about this?

Comment: @homerboy I'm assuming your nav bar is 25px tall. Did you set both `position: relative ` and `top: -25px` on the anchor element?

Comment: Ah, understood. Thanks for that, I got it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your fixed nav [Home, Resume, etc] is blocking the top border of Resume.

I suggest that you decrease the padding-bottom of your navigation and decrease the padding-top of RESUME.